# TCPDF, cant include external javascript files in cakephp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, tcpdf

all, I am struggling a lot for finding a solution. i want to include a external javascript file into the tcpdf page like i did in cakephp normal view page

```
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery.imagemapster');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery.imagemapster.min');
```

actually I am working with imagemapster tool, which is used for make selectable areas on images. i have a normal cakephp view page. which displays a images with some selceted areas(which is marked using imagemapster). i want to make a pdf for the same file.
so i need to include the imagemapster script into my pdf page so that i can mark the same image using the tool.
i used includeJS function

```
           $js = <<<EOD

           $('#teeth').mapster({
           showToolTip: true,
           fillColor: '0000FF',
           fillOpacity: 1,
           mapKey: 'alt',
           strokeWidth: 1,
           stroke: true,
           staticState: false,
       });

    $pdf->IncludeJS($js);
```

for marking the given areas on the image. but i want to include the imagemapster jquery files to work this code. so what should i do?
 i have two doubts.

1. can we include external jquery files into tcpdf.if  possible, how?
2. i have already a working view.ctp files which contain the marked images. is any option for map that image inside tcpdf.or can i directly convert that view.ctp to pdf. any options?

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible. It should be obvious that pdf is a binary format and your view is generating that file. You can't use javascript inside a pdf document. You'll have to come up with your own render method to render whatever you want on top of the images inside your pdf.